# I want to create a signin form that takes user interest in the form of tags just like that of the stack overflow (just a general idea)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to create a login form that takes user interest in the form of tags just like that of the stack overflow, how do you make that? Check example below.

[this is how i want to make the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCZoH.png)

Comment: A quick google search gave me [this](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) and [this](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/). give them a read

Comment: what you have tried so far.. throwing  question like an interviewer will get you down voted

Comment: 1) http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive 2) http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ 3) http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ 4) http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this :

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" value="java,php" data-role="tagsinput"></input>
```

For CSS, call these two files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.css">
```

For Javascript, call these two files:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/dist/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>
```

The code will generate the result like you want.